# out_of_range at memory location c++

Tags: c++, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

In this program the user enters two strings into the command line. One of which is a numbers and the other is a string. The program is meant to check whether the number and the string inputted are equivalent based on the numbers/letters on each button of a phone dial. I am getting an exception that says:

> ```
> Unhandled exception at 0x775DDAE8 in Project10.exe: 
> Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0018F158.
> ```

any help is greatly appreciated thank you so much :)

```
using namespace std;

bool checkPswd(string keyStrokes, string password) {
    string temp;
    string temp2;
    bool temporary = 1;
    string phoneButtons[10] = {
        "", ""
        "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl",
        "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz"
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < keyStrokes.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j < 10; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < phoneButtons[j].length(); k++) {
                temp = phoneButtons[j];
                if (password.at(k) == temp.at(k)) {
                    temp2 = +(char)k;
                }
                else {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << temp2;
    for (int m = 0; m < temp2.length(); m++) {
        if (temp2.at(m) == keyStrokes.at(m)) {
            //keep searching
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        cout << "Please input the key strokes from the phone and the password." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    string keyStrokes = argv[1];
    string password = argv[2];


    bool check;

    check = checkPswd(keyStrokes, password);
    if (check) {
        cout << "Password Verified" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Wrong Password" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
for (int k = 0; k < phoneButtons[j].length(); k++) {
```

k will iterate here from 0 to one less than the number of characters in `phoneButtons[j]

```
   if (password.at(k)  // ... rest of the code is irrelevant
```

Pop quiz: If `password` has fewer characters than `phoneButtons[j]`, what do you think is going to happen here?

```
for (int m = 0; m < temp2.length(); m++) {
    if (temp2.at(m) == keyStrokes.at(m)) {
```

Same bug here too. I haven't analyzed the rest of the shown code for any other occurences of the same logical bug.

This is why you should use `#include <algorithm>`, instead of using these kinds error-prone C-style `for` loops. `std::find()` is much less error-prone than this kind of C-style loop-based search.

Comment: So by this explanation I take it that you mean I should fix it to <= rather than just <, which i get but it does not help with the main issue :/

Comment: I mean that if you iterate from 0 and up to the length of one string, but then accessing the same range of characters in the second string, then the second string better be at least as big as the first string, otherwise you end up with undefined behavior, and a crash. If `phoneButtons[j].length()` is 5, and `password` is 2 characters long, what do you think your code will do when you try `password.at(4)`?

Comment: So how could i search a string array for individual characters. I am so confused.  Sorry for being a total nuisance, but I've only started using c++ about 2 and a half weeks ago.

Comment: I've started using C++ about 20 years ago, and I'm still learning new things, every once in a while. `std::string` has a `find()` method that looks for a character in the string. It's much easier to use `find()` instead of manually iterating over each character in the string. In your case, you keep getting the end of the string wrong, using the length of a different string for iterating over the string in question. Use `std::string`'s `find()` method. Or, use the generic `std::find` in `#include <algorithm>`.

Answer (score 1):

#### The cause of the problem

Manually looping through multiple arrays and reading from them is error prone.

- Your loop keeps overwriting `temp2`, not appending to it.
- Later, your code is assuming that `temp2` is the same length as `keystrokes`.

This is why you don't do it "by hand" the way you did. It is hard to keep track of everything perfectly and hard to always know it is safe to access a given index.

#### A better way

A better approach is to make a function that translates one thing to another. You can implement a highly generic way of doing that using iterators. The iterators can refer to many data structures, and can even read/write streams. It is highly flexible.

Since the compiler can "see everything" and knows everything about all of the types, it can generate extremely efficient code that is very safe.

Here is an iterator-based implementation that translates the characters to digits, then compares the digits.

### [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/682602eadbc6bed6)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<
    typename InputIt,
    typename OutputIt,
    typename V = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type,
    typename OutTag = typename std::iterator_traits<OutputIt>::iterator_category,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<OutTag, std::output_iterator_tag>::value>::type
>
OutputIt convertToDigits(InputIt st, InputIt en, OutputIt dest)
{
    using ButtonPair = std::pair<char, int>;
    using ButtonLookup = std::vector<ButtonPair>;

    static ButtonLookup lookup{
        { 'a', 2 }, { 'b', 2 }, { 'c', 2 },
        { 'd', 3 }, { 'e', 3 }, { 'f', 3 },
        { 'g', 4 }, { 'h', 4 }, { 'i', 4 },
        { 'j', 5 }, { 'k', 5 }, { 'l', 5 },
        { 'm', 6 }, { 'n', 6 }, { 'o', 6 },
        { 'p', 7 }, { 'q', 7 }, { 'r', 7 }, { 's', 7 },
        { 't', 8 }, { 'u', 8 }, { 'v', 8 },
        { 'w', 9 }, { 'x', 9 }, { 'y', 9 }, { 'z', 9 }
    };

    auto ls = std::begin(lookup);
    auto le = std::end(lookup);

    std::for_each(st, en, [&](char c) {
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
            c += 'a' - 'A';
        auto m = std::find_if(ls, le, [&](auto const& p) {
            return p.first == c;
        });
        if (m != le)
            *dest++ = m->second;
    });
    return dest;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
        return 1;
    std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv + argc);

    std::string const& numbers = args.at(1);
    std::string const& characters = args.at(2);

    std::cout << " Chars: \"" << characters << '\"' << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Check: \"" << numbers << '\"' << std::endl;

    std::vector<int> digits;

    convertToDigits(std::begin(characters), std::end(characters), 
        std::back_inserter(digits));

    for (int& digit : digits)
        digit += '0';

    std::cout << "Expect: \"" << std::string(
        std::begin(digits), std::end(digits)) << '\"' << std::endl;

    bool match = std::equal(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers),
            std::begin(digits), std::end(digits));

    return !match;
}
```

#### How it works

`convertToDigits` takes a pair of iterators, referring to the beginning and end of the range to convert. The third parameter is an output iterator, used to store output.

The `main` function sets up a `vector` for the digit `int` values, and uses `std::back_inserter` to make an output iterator that does `push_back` on the vector each time it is stored into.

The translator function simply does a linear search in a lookup table. I chose a linear search because the list is so small. It will be tightly packed in memory and has very low overhead. Speed won't matter here, anyway. It is instantaneous.

I add `'0'` to the digit values to convert them to ASCII, so they are comparable to the command line string of characters.

The rest is obvious, see if the converted string matched the expected string, and exit with 0 exit code if it matched.

Comment: How does this explain to OP why they are accessing memory using an out of range index?

Comment: @JamesAdkison It does now.